# How to add radio button in the row JSF 2

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Please refer the following image:

[image]

and my code is as follows:

```
<h:selectOneRadio group="result" value="#{sampleCOntroller.testRslt}">
                             <p:column>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="PS" />
                            </p:column>
                             <p:column>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="NE" />
                            </p:column>
                             <p:column>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="NA" />
                            </p:column>
                        </h:selectOneRadio>
```

but I don't even get the radio buttons and just blank is displayed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Where in the `h:selectOneRadio` documentation did you read it supports `p:column` inside it?

Comment: Just remove these column. You need to use some CSS to get this implemented.